# Determine total pages with Google list method

Tags: pagination, google-api, blogger

I'm working with the [Google Blogger API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/list) and am finding its forcing pagination on me when retrieving a list of blog posts. It looks like several of the Google APIs offer a List method to return a list of [items]. The request has a `maxResults` parameter, which defaults to various numbers depending on the API (apparently 10 for Blogger).

The problem is I'm not seeing it returning the total number of posts or pages and my app has a progress bar to show the percentage of total posts that it has processed.

So I need to know how many posts there are total.

I found that the [YouTube API's response for](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) `PlayListItems` includes a `pageInfo` object with the total number of results in it.

Is there something like this that I'm just missing for [Blogger Posts](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/list) or do they really require paging without providing a way to get the total page count?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @DaImTo I'm not asking for debugging help & my code is working. I'm not sure what the point of confusion is for you. The question has a clear problem statement prefixed with "The problem is" and ends with my specific question about what data is available from the API response. There's not really anything to reproduce other than a response from the REST service which you can see how to get by following the Blogger API link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Posts: list](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/list) returns a special type of response.  It includes only the next page token and a list of the posts.  The same is true for Pages.

```
{
  "kind": "blogger#postList",
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "items": [
    [posts Resource][2]
  ]
}
```

Most of the other google APIs will return totalResults, Which is the total number of rows that the request could return with out paging.   Blogger doesn't do this as shown above.  You can get around it in the following manner.

[Blogs: get](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/blogs/get) returns a [blog Resource](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/blogs#resource) will return the information about the blog including the number of posts and pages it contains.  This is the only way to my knowledge to get a full result of the number of rows.

```
 "posts": {
  "totalItems": 395,
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/1969422610982987741/posts"
 },
 "pages": {
  "totalItems": 1,
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/1969422610982987741/pages"
 },
```

Comment: Thanks DalmTo. I was afraid of that. The problem with getting the total items from the Blog resource is it might be greater than the results of list posts, since list posts may be filtered (e.g. by a date range).

Comment: Blogger api is very limited there is really no other way that I am aware of